How to customize width of a modal form created by createOptionForm method in filament php
Below is my code for creating a modal form. How can I customize its width? I'd like to be a bit smaller
->createOptionForm([
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255)
                            ->unique(modifyRuleUsing: function (Unique $rule) {
                                return $rule->where('user_id', auth()->id());
                            }),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('stock')
                            ->required()
                            ->integer()
                            ->minValue(1)
                            ->maxLength(255),
                    ])


->createOptionAction(fn ($action) => $action->modalWidth('sm'))

Reference:
https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/pull/12352#issuecomment-2058382669

You can use grid that gives ability to create column(s) inside it
Grid::make(8)->schema([
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                            ->required()
                            ->maxLength(255)
                            ->unique(modifyRuleUsing: function (Unique $rule) {
                                return $rule->where('user_id', auth()->id());
                            })
                            ->columnSpan(4),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('stock')
                            ->required()
                            ->integer()
                            ->minValue(1)
                            ->maxLength(255)
                            ->columnSpan(4),
                    ])

For details; https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/layout/grid
